# SingleChildScrollView not working for password textfield in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am currently creating my first flutter application. So, when I was testing the login and sign up page. I encountered a problem.

The SingleChildScrollView() is not working in my Flutter login and Signin page for the password textfield only. The SingleChildScrollView() works perfectly for the email textfield. Can someone help me .

[image: Login view when not entering anything]

[image: When entering password]

Code of Login page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:secure_pass/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:secure_pass/services/auth/auth_exceptions.dart';
import 'package:secure_pass/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:secure_pass/utilities/dialogs/error_dialog.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children:[
                //App icon
                Icon(
                 Icons.android,
                 size: 100,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25),
                
                //Hello Again
                Text(
                  'Hello Again!',
                  style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                    fontSize: 52,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  'Welcome back, you\'ve been missed!',
                  style: TextStyle( 
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50),
          
                //email textfield
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _email,
                        enableSuggestions: false,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter your email here',
                          border: InputBorder.none
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
          
                //Password textfield
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _password,
                        obscureText: true,
                        enableSuggestions: false,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter your password here',
                          border: InputBorder.none
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
          
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final email = _email.text;
                    final password = _password.text;
                    try {
                      await AuthService.firebase().logIn(
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                      );
                      final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
                      if (user?.isEmailVerified ?? false) {
                        // user's email is verified
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          passwordsRoute,
                          (route) => false,
                        );
                      } else {
                        // user's email is NOT verified
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          verifyEmailRoute,
                          (route) => false,
                        );
                      }
                    } on UserNotFoundAuthException {
                      await showErrorDialog(
                        context,
                        'User not found',
                      );
                    } on WrongPasswordAuthException {
                      await showErrorDialog(
                        context,
                        'Wrong credentials',
                      );
                    } on GenericAuthException {
                      await showErrorDialog(
                        context,
                        'Authentication error',
                      );
                    }
                  },
          
                  //log in button
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),              
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 25),
                
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      registerRoute,
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                  },
          
                  //Not Registered yet ?
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const[
                      Text(
                        'Not registered yet?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ' Register now',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by `works perfectly for the email textfield.`, Do you mean  you are unable to scroll up and down?

Comment: I meant that the screen automatically moves up when I'm entering data in the email text field @griffins

Comment: On scroll do you get the password widget too?

Comment: Yeah, even the password textfield comes up when I'm entering my email.

Comment: This is the expected behavior right, or you want both email and password fields above the keyboard at all time?

Comment: I want both the email and the password textfield to come up, when the user is entering his data in the respective text fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the "Center" widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can add bottom padding to the email text field.

```dart
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 25,
                        right: 25,
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 32.0,
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want both the email and the password textfield to come up, when the user is entering his data in the respective text fields.

In order to achieve in your scaffold set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to `true` and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Just Add `reverse: true` on SingleChildScrollView.

```
child: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Column(
```