# Keyboard covering dropdown widget

Tags: flutter

I have made a dropdown menu, but when selecting items, the keyboard prevents the items from being displayed
What is the solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: show a simple code to your question

Comment: Wrapping your entire Scaffold with using a SingleChildScrollView widget

Answer (score 0):

You might try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73047628/12172300

```
// Just Add reverse: true on SingleChildScrollView.
child: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Column(
```

Answer (score 0):

use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: // your widgets here
);
```